# How to implement print function support for chrome 77

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfstamper

I am using below code for print function. But it's not working in chrome 77.

> pdfStamper.addJavaScript("this.print({bUI:
>   true,bSilent:false,bShrinkToFit: true});");